# Swift to Metal struct sizes different - padding required

Tags: swift, metal

I have the following struct in Swift

```
public struct PointWithValue2D {
    let x: uint!
    let y: uint!
    let value: Float!

    public init(_ x: uint, _ y: uint, _ value: Float) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

The size of this struct is 24 bytes. It was my understanding when I had a Metal version of this struct, that the size would be the same.

However, in order for my struct to work in Metal I had to pad the properties out to this:

```
struct PointWithValue2D {
    uint x;
    uint xPad;
    uint y;
    uint yPad;
    float value;
    float valuePad;
};
```

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: I assume the type you're actually using in Swift is `UInt`, since there is no `uint` type (unless you've created a typealias). In that case, on 64-bit platforms (i.e., all current Apple platforms), [`UInt` is 64 bits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint). In Metal, [`uint` is 32 bits](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf). That explains at least the discrepancy in the size of the integers. Use a fixed-size type like `UInt32` in Swift to make it agree with Metal's `uint`.

Comment: Thanks again @warrenm ! Always there with the Metal answers? Will there be a new book out soon?

Comment: Not for a long while yet.